# How to apply tier price with custom option product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-options, shopping-cart, tierprice

I have a product with more than 5 custom option in Magento and I want to apply tier price rules on a combination of custom option product in the cart.

Ex. I have tier price rules like

```
Buy 3 for $95.00  each and save 5%
Buy 5 for $90.00  each and save 10%
Buy 10 for $90.00  each and save 10%
```

and Size is my custom option so
If I add the product with Size 5 with Qty 2 and Size 10 with Qty 1 so my 'Buy 3 for $95.00  each and save 5%' rule is applied to both product.

How can I achieve this in Magento 2?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried by creating Cart price rule ?

Comment: Like for Product attribute combination and Product subselection

Comment: Yes, I have tried with Cart Price Rule but no success.